# Query for max CPU, Memory and System Queue length

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I am looking for a query to find maximum CPU, Memory and System Queue length for last month. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't store granular history going back that far. You have a couple of options:

Option 1: Look at what's happening now. Run [sp_BlitzFirst](https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/), one of the scripts in the [open source First Responder Kit](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/tree/master). It takes a 5-second sample of what's happening on the server right now, and gives you those metrics. Try experimenting with @ExpertMode = 1 to see even more details.

Option B: start collecting it yourself. Set up sp_BlitzFirst to run in an Agent job every 15 minutes, logging the metrics to tables, and then use the Power BI Dashboard for DBAs to visualize it. [Here are instructions.](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/first-responder-kit-power-bi-dashboard/)

Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of those open source tools.